# Shows php array in Nested Structure

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(
[country] => India, [state] => Kerala, [city] => Kottayam)
            array([country] => India, [state] => Bihar, [city] => Vijayavada)
            array([country] => India, [state] => Kerala, [city] => Cochin)
            array([country] => Pakistan, [state] => Sate1, [city] => City1)
            array([country] => Pakistan, [state] => Sate1, [city] => City2)
```

tried array_unique but because of same index it fails returns only the first array

And also I would like to print the above array as

```
<div class="location-content">
    <h3>India</h3>
        <h4>Kerala</h4>
        <ul class="countries">
            <li><a href="#"> Kottayam</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Cochin</a> </li>
        </ul>
    <h4>Bihar</h4>
    <ul class="countries">
            <li><a href="#"> Vijayavada</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Pakistan</h3>
        <h4>Sate1</h4>
        <ul class="countries">
            <li><a href="#"> City1</a> </li>
        </ul>
    <h4>Sate2</h4>
    <ul class="countries">
            <li><a href="#"> City2</a> </li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: Tried array_unique to get a list of indexes? Are you constructing this array manually or is this a result of a DB query?

Comment: it is from db query. already array values are unique

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function arrayUnique($myArray)
{
    if(!is_array($myArray))
           return $myArray;

    foreach ($myArray as &$myvalue){
        $myvalue=serialize($myvalue);
    }

    $myArray=array_unique($myArray);

    foreach ($myArray as &$myvalue){
        $myvalue=unserialize($myvalue);
    }

    return $myArray;

} 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(arrayUnique($arr));
```